# What is the proper way of checking for falsyness of trimmed strings in MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, boolean-expression

Let's assume that I have a table called users, with three columns - id, name, and nickname.

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| id |  name   | nickname       |
+----+---------+----------------+
|  1 | Alice   | Allie          |
|  2 | Bob     | B              |
|  3 | Charles |       Charlie  |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to display the concatenated name and nickname (both trimmed), if the nickname is not, when trimmed, an empty string. If the trimmed nickname is empty, then only the name should be displayed.

I've tried doing this:

```
SELECT
  users.id,
  CONCAT(
    TRIM(users.name),
    IF(
      TRIM(users.nickname),
      CONCAT(' - ',TRIM(users.nickname)),
      ''
    )
  )
FROM users
```

expecting it to return this

```
Alice Allie
Bob B
Charles Charlie
```

However, only the names are returned, and the nicknames are not. What am I doing wrong? The appropriate fiddle can be found [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5621d/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, the truth/false of a string is the same as whether you can cast the string to an integer. If the string casts to the integer 0, it is "false". If the string casts to anything besides 0, it is "true".

Casting a string to an integer in MySQL means to read any leading digits and use the numeric value. If there are no leading digits, assume 0, which makes it "false".

```
mysql> select 'abc123' + 0;
+--------------+
| 'abc123' + 0 |
+--------------+
|            0 |
+--------------+

mysql> select '123abc' + 0;
+--------------+
| '123abc' + 0 |
+--------------+
|          123 |
+--------------+
```

In your case, you are testing `IF(TRIM(users.nickname), <true-expr>, <false-expr>)` but it's very likely that the nicknames do not start with digits (unless the user is a rap artist :-), so they will all be cast as 0, so they will result in the "false" expression.

If you're testing for the length of the string, you should do that:

```
IF(LENGTH(TRIM(user.nickname) > 0, <true-expr>, <false-expr>)
```

The answer from @SalmanA is a good alternative method to produce the result you want, but I am writing this answer to explain why you saw the behavior you saw.

Answer (score 1):

`CONCAT_WS` should do the trick. It skips NULL values but you explicitly need to handle empty strings:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-'
               , NULLIF(TRIM(users.name), '')
               , NULLIF(TRIM(users.nickname), ''))
FROM users
```